# How to load two load two models in @RequestBody at a time in Spring REST Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring. I want to load data in two models Trade and Skill.
Written code sample is here - 
Controller Code -

```
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String Create(@RequestBody TradeSkill tradeskill) {
        System.out.println(tradeskill);
        return "record is created";
    }
```

Parent Request Body -

```
class TradeSkill {
    @Autowired
    protected Skill skill;
    @Autowired
    protected Trade trade;

    public TradeSkill() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TradeSkill [skill=" + skill + ", trade=" + trade + "]";
    }
}
```

Json is -

```
{
    "skill" : {
    "name" : "new skill"
    },
    "trade" : {
    "trade_name" : "Trade"
    }
}
```

Console Output is - 
TradeSkill [skill=null, trade=null]

What am i doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: TradeSklll class not properly implemented. @Autowired not required. Need parameterized constructor and getter-setter. Trade and Skill classes should follow the same.

Comment: I think you should be read @Autowried before you use it :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider doing following:

1. Drop `@Autowired` from `TradeSkill`, add getters and setters for `trade` and `skill` fields.
2. Make sure that `name` and `tradeName` fields within `Skill` and `Trade` models respectively also got getters and setters.
3. Fix your request json, replace `trade_name` with `tradeName`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bohdan Levchenko suggested in his answer, classes should look like below:

**TradeSkill.java**

```
public class TradeSkill {
    protected Skill skill;
    protected Trade trade;

    public Skill getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(Skill skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

    public Trade getTrade() {
        return trade;
    }

    public void setTrade(Trade trade) {
        this.trade = trade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TradeSkill [skill=" + skill + ", trade=" + trade + "]";
    }
}
```

**Trade.java**

```
public class Trade {
    private String trade_name;

    public String getTrade_name() {
        return trade_name;
    }

    public void setTrade_name(String trade_name) {
        this.trade_name = trade_name;
    }
}
```

**Skill.java**

```
public class Skill {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Requested JSON should be like:

```
{
    "skill" : {
    "name" : "new skill"
    },
    "trade" : {
    "trade_name" : "Trade"
    }
}
```